# Add CSS in Laravel 8

Tags: css, laravel-8

I put my CSS file inside `public/css` folder. I added CSS file in head section like below.

```
<link href="{{ url('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

But CSS is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you can't just use a relative URL like:

```
<link href="./css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 5):

This is working for me in **Laravel 8** (make sure your files are in the public folder)

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 8, make sure your files are in the public folder and reference them like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url('css/app.css') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::to('css/app.css') }}">
```

Comment: make sure you have css files under public folder.